# Avoiding code duplication in a specialized template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have two similar templates, one with 1 parameter and other with 2 parameters:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2=void>
struct foo {
  T1 m_t1;
  T2 m_t2;
  foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) : m_t1(t1), m_t2(t2) {}
  T1 t1() { return m_t1; }
  T2 t2() { return m_t2; }
};

template<typename T1>
struct foo<T1,void> {
  T1 m_t1;
  foo(T1 t1) : m_t1(t1) {}
  T1 t1() { return m_t1; }
};
```

Notice the code duplication for all the T1-related stuff. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your code as is has intrinsic ambiguity beyond the problem you're trying to solve: For single parameter template the compiler won't be able to resolve the template to use. E.g.: http://ideone.com/7wcB6Z

Comment: @icepack What do you mean? Doesn't your code fail, as expected, because the class doesn't have a default constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution to this is to have as much code as possible in a base class. For example:

```
template<typename T1>
struct foo_base {
    T1 m_t1;
    explicit foo_base(T1 t1) : m_t1(t1) {}
    T1 t1() const { return m_t1; }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2=void>
struct foo : foo_base<T1> {
    T2 m_t2;
    foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) : foo_base<T1>(t1), m_t2(t2) {}
    T2 t2() const { return m_t2; }
};

template<typename T1>
struct foo<T1,void> : foo_base<T1> {
    explicit foo(T1 t1) : foo_base<T1>(t1) {}
};
```

Comment: What does "explicit" have to do with the question at hand?

Comment: @7cows: Good practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: and while you are at it, some const-correctness stuff could also be added

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general sort of question.

In this case, you could put the `T1`-related stuff in a base class. In general, you should avoid the one-two-many problem. What you're doing here could also be achieved by `std::tuple`, which is also part of the Boost library.

For what it's worth, `tuple` works by composing any number of base classes.

Answer (score 2):

Looking closely at your code, you are reimplementing `std::tuple`. Exchange the `t1` and `t2` methods for the free function `std::get<N>` and you have everything (and maybe more) `std::tuple` gives you. For convenience, if it *has* to be a method, consider this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct foo {
  typedef std::tuple<Ts...> Tup;
  Tup m_ts;
  foo(Ts... ts) : m_ts{ts...} {} //!

  template <unsigned N> 
  std::tuple_element<N, Tup> t() { return std::get<N>(Tup); }
};
```

For the `//!`: Of course you could make that constructor a (variadic) template and just forward the arguments to the tuple. Oh, and the accessor could/should be overloaded for const and nonconst and return appropiate references to the tuple elements...

But seriously, it's not worth the sweat. Just use plain `std::tuple`. Except of course you oversimplified the problem and you are doing something different than you told us.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance would solve your problem. Define a one-parameter base class that provides the `T1` stuff and make the two-parameter version inherit that.

Answer (score 0):

There are three numbers: 0, 1 and infinity.

Oh, and counting starts at 0, not 1!

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct first_type {}
template<typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct first_type {
  typedef T0 type;
};
template<typename... Ts>
using FirstType = typename first_type<Ts...>::type;

template<typename T0, typename Rest, typename=void>
struct foo_impl;

template<typename... Ts>
struct foo_augment {};
template<typename T1>
struct foo_augment<T1> {
  T1 m_t1;
  T1 t1() const { return m_t1; }
  T1 t1() { return m_t1; }
};

template<typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct foo_impl< T0, std::tuple<Ts...>, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof...(Ts)<2) >::type >:
  foo_augment<Ts...>
{
  // use FirstType<Ts...> to get at the second type of your argument pack
  foo_impl( T0 t0, Ts... ts ):
    m_t0(t0), foo_augment<Ts...>(ts...)
  {};
  T0 m_t0;
  T0 t0() { return m_t0; }
  T0 t0() const { return m_t0; }
};
template<typename T0, typename... Ts>
using foo = foo_impl<T0, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

Now, note that there is lots of boilerplate above, a fair amount more than the amount of duplicated code you used.

Instead of the `...` mess, you could use a "reserved value" for `T1` to indicate "not there", like `void`.  In that case, you can use this trick with the constructor:

```
  template<typename... Ts, typename=typename std::enable_if< ((sizeof...(Ts)==0) == (std::is_same<T1, void>::value)) && (sizeof...(Ts)<2) >::type >
  foo_impl( T0 t0, Ts&&... ts ):
    m_t0(t0), foo_augment<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
  {};
```

where the constructor is variardic, but SFINAE means that the `Ts...` parameter pack must be 0 elements iff `T1` is `void`, and must be 1 element iff `T1` is not `void`.

(Code not compiled yet, but basic design should be sound).