# recursive template inheritance code duplication

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template< class T, unsigned S >
struct my_iterator;

template< class T >
struct my_iterator< T, 1 >
{ 
    T* p;
};

template< class T, unsigned S >
struct my_iterator : my_iterator< T, S / 2 >
{
    static_assert ((S & (S - 1)) == 0, "S must be a power of 2");

    using my_iterator< T, S / 2 >::p;

    unsigned burp() {return (*p) + S;}
};

int main()
{
    int v = 10;

    my_iterator< int, 8 > a;
    a.p = &v;
    std::cout << a.burp() << std::endl;

    my_iterator< int, 4 >& b = a;
    std::cout << b.burp() << std::endl;

    my_iterator< int, 1 > c;
    c.p = &v;
    std::cout << c.burp() << std::endl; // error: no member named 'burp'

    return 0;
}
```

This will fix the error:

```
template< class T >
struct my_iterator< T, 1 >
{ 
    unsigned burp() {return (*p) + 1;}

    T* p;
};
```

but in my real code I have many methods, not just `burp`, all dependent on `S` and `p`, that would all need to be implemented twice, once in the general class and once in the specialization. Is there any way to avoid the duplicate code? I saw this similar question:

[Avoiding code duplication in a specialized template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985075/avoiding-code-duplication-in-a-specialized-template)

but the answer will not work in my case because I'll end up with many copies of `p`, one at each level of the recursive hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, if you have a recursion stop value of 1 which you want to still use, you can just move the stop value to 0...
This way `my_iterator<T,1>` still has the default implementation.

```
    template< class T, unsigned S >
    struct my_iterator;

    template< class T >
    struct my_iterator< T, 0 >
    { 
        T* p;

    };

    template< class T, unsigned S >
    struct my_iterator : my_iterator< T, S / 2 >
    {
        static_assert ((S & (S - 1)) == 0, "S must be a power of 2");

        using my_iterator< T, S / 2 >::p;

        unsigned burp() {return (*p) + S;}
    };
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, thanks! Also, in this case I wouldn't want to be able to call any methods with S==0 anyway, it wouldn't make sense, so this works out perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

An other way is to move specific stuff in an other structure:

```
template <typename T> struct opt_ptr { T* p; };

// to be able to use std::conditional with non instantiated type.
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template<typename T, unsigned S>
struct my_iterator :
    std::conditional<S == 1,
                     identity<opt_ptr<T>>,
                     identity<my_iterator<T, S / 2>>>::type::type
{
    static_assert ((S & (S - 1)) == 0, "S must be a power of 2");

    using opt_ptr<T>::p; // Note that you may use this->p to avoid this line

    unsigned burp() {return *p + S;}
    // Other methods using S and p.
};
```

Comment: `my_iterator<T, 0>` inheriting from itself is also a problem.

Comment: @atb: only `opt_ptr<T, 1>` has `T* p;`, all others are empty classes.

Comment: What stops the recursive inheritance? Wouldn't I still need a specialization of my_iterator<T, 0> or my_iterator<T, 1>?

Comment: @atb: you're right, recursion has to be stopped with an empty `my_iterator<T, 0>`... (or use other tricks for conditional inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass down S to the base template, and move the method there.

```
template< class T, unsigned S, unsigned N >
struct my_iterator;

template< class T, unsigned S >
struct my_iterator< T,S, 1 >
{  
    unsigned burp() {return (*p) + S;}

    T* p;
};

template< class T, unsigned S, unsigned N = S >
struct my_iterator : my_iterator< T, S, N / 2 >
{
    static_assert ((S & (S - 1)) == 0, "S must be a power of 2");

    using my_iterator< T,S, N / 2 >::p;

};
```

Comment: You also have to redefine the base template to take three parameters.

Comment: @atb ok, i've opened my VS to get a compiling version of what i meant.

Comment: This does avoid the duplication but it changes the functionality. I can't cast `my_iterator< int, 8 >` to `my_iterator< int, 4 >` anymore and this is a requirement of the design. I can cast it to `my_iterator< int, 8, 4 >` but then burp returns the wrong value.

Comment: @atb Do you need the recursion all the way down to 1 ?

Comment: Yes I do. I know I could get the same functionality without any inheritance, using `reinterpret_cast`, but I'm trying to do this the "right" way. I'm trying to work something out with an additional non-specialized base class and conditional inheritance with `std::conditional`...but no luck so far.